# Multiple user inputs through one function with a single parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that uses two functions to get a letter grade and get a score average. I am stuck on what I have down below and have been researching for longer than I should have for this assignment. The two functions that need to be used is `calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5)` and `gradeLetter(grade)`. I figured out how to get the average but stuck on `gradeLetter` function.

```
def main():

    grade1 = int(input("Please enter your first grade: "))
    grade2 = int(input("Please enter your second grade: "))
    grade3 = int(input("Please enter your third grade: "))
    grade4 = int(input("Please enter your fourth grade: "))
    grade5 = int(input("Please enter your fifth grade: "))
    
    avg=calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5)

    print(avg)

def gradeLetter(grade):
    if grade > 90 or grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif grade > 80 or grade < 90:
        return 'B'
    elif grade > 70 or grade < 80:
        return 'C'
    elif grade > 60 or grade < 70:
        return 'D'
    elif grade < 60:
        return 'F'

def calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5):
    avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5) / 5
    return avg

main()
```

Comment: I overlooked this as well, I have to learn to take it one step at a time. I am new to programming. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `gradeLetter` will always return "A" the way you've written it because `grade <= 100` will always be True (with meaningful inputs).
2. You can condense `gradeLetter` to check only one side of the inequality since you're using `elif`.
3. Finally, simply call the function in `main` after you print the average:

```
def main():

    grade1 = int(input("Please enter your first grade: "))
    grade2 = int(input("Please enter your second grade: "))
    grade3 = int(input("Please enter your third grade: "))
    grade4 = int(input("Please enter your fourth grade: "))
    grade5 = int(input("Please enter your fifth grade: "))
  
    avg=calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5)

    print(avg)
    print(gradeLetter(avg)) #add this line

def gradeLetter(grade): 
    if grade >= 90: #modify your conditional statements
        return 'A'
    elif grade >= 80:
        return 'B'
    elif grade >= 70:
        return 'C'
    elif grade >= 60:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have everything working now. I think I have to not overlook things so much. Appreciate your time

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment due to lack of reputation :/)
You need to change the logic statement to `and`:
`if grade > 90 and grade <= 100:`

on another note, this is even simpler:
`if 90 < grade <= 100:`

Comment: Thank you so much, I overlooked that at least 40 times and thought it was something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the gradeLetter function inside `main()` as

```
avg = calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5)
print(gradeLetter(avg))
```

Also `gradeLetter` method has wrong conditions to compare for.
Modify function as

```
def gradeLetter(grade):
    if grade > 90 and grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif grade > 80 and grade < 90:
        return 'B'
    elif grade > 70 and grade < 80:
        return 'C'
    elif grade > 60 and grade < 70:
        return 'D'
    elif grade < 60:
        return 'F'
```

Else your code with `or` conditions will fail for this output:

```
Please enter your first grade: 1
Please enter your second grade: 2
Please enter your third grade: 3
Please enter your fourth grade: 4
Please enter your fifth grade: 5
3.0
A
```